# How can I generate a list in Excel based on criteria?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to make a list of codes based on a format of AAA 001 A 001. So I have what they should be - I should have PIC 001 to 062, A to E, 001 to 012. I need all combinations, so

```
PIC 001 A 001
PIC 001 A 002
PIC 001 A 003 up to 012
...
Then PIC 001 B 001 to 012, and so on until PIC 001 E 001 to 012
...
Then PIC 002, A to E, 001 to 012
```

That's 3,720 combinations. I've tried making lookups to make a count within each of the three columns and generating +1 on the row above, I've tried IF statements to try and work it out, but I'm getting nowhere.

Comment: You will need to use ROUNDOWN(ROW/12) this will help generate multiples of 12, work out where this fits and place in something similar for any other multiples you requires, same for letters but you will need to create a lookup table i.e A=1 and so on. you wont want to be using IFS that will get too messy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If one has the dynamic array formula SEQUENCE(), Put this in the first cell and Excel will spill the results down:

```
="PIC " & TEXT(INT(SEQUENCE(3720,,0)/60)+1,"000")&" "&CHAR(MOD(INT(SEQUENCE(3720,,0)/12),5)+65)&" "&TEXT(MOD(SEQUENCE(3720,,0),12)+1,"000")
```

If not then replace the `SEQUENCE(3720,,0)` with `ROW(A1)-1` and copy down 3720 rows.

```
="PIC " & TEXT(INT((ROW(A1)-1)/60)+1,"000")&" "&CHAR(MOD(INT((ROW(A1)-1)/12),5)+65)&" "&TEXT(MOD((ROW(A1)-1),12)+1,"000")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks - your logic looks right and the screenshot is perfect, but it's not working for me. An error message says I've entered too many arguments.



For the CHAR(MOD(INT(ROW(A1)-1,5)+65) segment, it highlights the 5 as the issue. When I change, remove or add to the 5, I get the same error of too many or too few arguments.



I've tried splitting the formula into three pieces to put together later, but that seems to mess with the A1 reference above.

Comment: @bluesquared see edit.